# How to open a link in a new tab with Python selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tabs, selenium-chromedriver

Please, advise on how to open a link in a new tab with Python selenium Chrome Webdriver. So, I am not asking how to simply open a new tab, nor on how to open a new tab with Firefox.

This one opens the same page in a new tab:

```
first_link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.ENTER)
```

This one too:

```
first_link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.ENTER)
```

alecxe answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088589/selenium-wont-open-a-new-url-in-a-new-tab-python-chrome) does not work since, I cannot get an url a link is pointing at. I need to simply emulate Right-mouse-click > "Open link in a new tab".

### Update

The problem turns out to be with the website https://www.pagesjaunes.fr itself. For some reason it give wrong urls for its entries in search results. For instance for element:

```
//*[@id="bi-bloc-0437413413085060110003C0001"]/div[2]/header/div[1]/div/h2/a[2]
```

Therefore, when the link of this element is attempted to be accessed via Selenium or requests, it redirects to the page of the search results itself. In light of this I decided to use a different approach to solving the issue.

Therefore I decided to abandon the approach of opening the link in a  new tab.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this :

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
```

Answer (score 0):

Below works for me great

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://tarunlalwani.com/post/")
action = ActionChains(driver)
elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("How To Debug Nginx Reverse Proxy Issues")
action\
    .move_to_element(elem)\
    .key_down(Keys.SHIFT)\
    .click(elem)\
    .key_up(Keys.SHIFT)\
    .perform()

driver.quit()
```

Comment: it opens a link in the same tab. I need it to be opened in a new tab

Comment: Mine opens a new windows and not a tab. But two windows in same browser

Answer (score -1):

you first need to " pip install keyboard "

```
keyboard.press("ctrl+t")
```