# opening link in new tab but only one window handle

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

# open a link in a new window
actions = ActionChains(driver)
about = driver.find_element_by_link_text('About')
actions.context_click(about).send_keys('t').perform()
print(driver.current_url)
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
print(len(driver.window_handles))
print(driver.current_url)
```

I tried to open a link in new tab by right clicking a link and selecting open as new tab but on inspecting the length of window_handles it is only one.So how I could I go to "About" page and why length of browser.handles=1?why not 2?

Comment: See this: [Opening new tabs in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python)

Comment: what if I have to explicitly open by clicking.Whats wrong in my code?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46015904/open-link-in-a-new-tab-with-python-selenium-chrome-webdriver/46016954#46016954)

Comment: It opened a link in new window. but i want to open in new tab (using firefox) .If I manage to open it in new tab then I am not able to switch to that page in selenium since window_handles length remains 1

Comment: How should I edit to get upvotes and answers.I lost my previlege to ask question and neither I am able to edit it :(