# Unable to open new tab in chrome, none of the solutions are working

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, web-applications, webdriver, salesforce

I am working on Salesforce automation. There is a scenario which uses the one time sign on:

1. I will log in to Salesforce application;
2. Open a new tab and click on login with Salesforce account;
3. Upload the excel and switch back to Salesforce tab.

I am able to login in Salesforce application but unable to open a new tab
I have already tried below solution:

Solution 1:

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);   
act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("t").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

Solution 2:

```
Robot robot=new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
```

Solution 3:

```
String KeyString = Keys.CONTROL+"t";
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(KeyString);
```

Solution 4:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"t");
```

Has anyone faced issue? What could be the possible solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening link in the new tab and switching between tabs (Selenium Webdriver + Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425797/opening-link-in-the-new-tab-and-switching-between-tabs-selenium-webdriver-pyt)

Comment: Nope, answer u mentioned is for MAC i am trying for windows. I have tried all possible solutions and unable to proceed further

Comment: The accepted answer is cross-platform.

Comment: I got the solution using javascript
`String newURL =("URL");
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   js.executeScript("window.open('"+newURL+"','_blank');");`

But i am still wondering why other solutions are not supporting !! strange

Thanks for your time @RatmirAsanov

Comment: Okey, good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavascriptExecutor to switch to the new tab. Switching doesn't work automatically. So it's a two phase solution.

```
 ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('http://example.com/','_blank');");
```

Above code will open example.com in a new tab.

Now you can switch using something like below:

```
Set<String> tab_handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
int number_of_tabs = tab_handles.size();
int new_tab_index = number_of_tabs-1;
driver.switchTo().window(tab_handles.toArray()[new_tab_index].toString());
```