# How to open the new link (generated after clicking an element in a web page) in a new tab using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have to try to click an element on a web page, and I want the link after the click should open in a new tab, here is the code snippet:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/main/div/sec[1]').click()

# Above code open the link but in the same tab.
```

I have tried the following code to open it in a new tab:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/main/div/sec[1]').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't').click()

# But it's not working.
```

How to open this in a new tab?

P.S.: This is not the link to open in a new tab, its the element to be opened on a new tab, so don't mark it as duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening link in the new tab and switching between tabs (Selenium WebDriver + Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425797/opening-link-in-the-new-tab-and-switching-between-tabs-selenium-webdriver-pyt)

Comment: @hashcode55 please read the both questions before marking it as duplicate

Comment: @KallolSamanta Can you update the question with the relevant HTML?

Comment: @KallolSamanta What do you mean by "opening an element in a new tab"? The only difference I see between the your question and duplicate question is you are trying to find the element by xpath.

Comment: @KallolSamanta, check out my answer (second not accepted one): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425797/opening-link-in-the-new-tab-and-switching-between-tabs-selenium-webdriver-pyt

Answer (score 0):

This should work in Java (Hope you can write this logic in Python),

To open a link in new tab

```
WebElement ele = wd.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
Actions link = new Actions(wd);   
link.keyDown(Keys.COMMAND).click(ele).keyUp(Keys.COMMAND).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Switch to new tab,

```
Set<String> windows = wd.getWindowHandles();
wd.switchTo().window((String) windows.toArray()[1]);
```