# New tab python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, tabs

I have a problem with a Code including Selenium:
when I opened a link in a new Tab, the Programm wasn't working on the new tab, instead it was going on on the old Tab. I tried to change Tab with *CTRL + TAB* but this didn't work. Then I tried the following Code, I found in another Question:
[Opening link in the new tab and switching between tabs (Selenium WebDriver + Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425797/opening-link-in-the-new-tab-and-switching-between-tabs-selenium-webdriver-pyt)

Also this didn't work...
Anyone an idea?

PS: I'm using Python 3.8.3

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
import time

username = "xxxxxxxxx"
password = "XXXXXXXXX"
Kunde = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"

PATH = "C:\Drivers\Webdriver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://areaclienti.gse.it/")
print(driver.title)

#some navigation in between
#some navigation in between
#some navigation in between
#some navigation in between

first_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-private/nb-layout/div[1]/div/div/div/div/nb-layout-column/div/app-my-services-container/mat-tab-group/div/mat-tab-body[2]/div/app-my-services-operator-list/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/app-operator-service-subscription/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/app-card-sm/mat-card/div[1]")

# Save the window opener (current window, do not mistake with tab... not the same).
main_window = driver.current_window_handle

driver = 1
# Open the link in a new tab by sending keystrokes on the element.
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.key_down(Keys.COMMAND)
actions.click(first_link)
actions.key_up(Keys.COMMAND)
actions.perform()

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

time.sleep(5)

# Close current tab.
driver.close()

time.sleep(5)

# Put the focus on the current window which will be the window opener.
driver.switch_to.window(main_window)

# Close the instance of the browser.
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I solved it.
The key is to use this Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
import time

#...

#...

actions = ActionChains(driver)
about = driver.find_element_by_xpath("enter your XPATH")
actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(about).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

Comment: Tried this, somehow, it doesn't open in a new tab