# How to make Selenium Chrome Driver to open on a new tab in a pre existing window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, raw-input, py2app

Hello I am currently working on a selenium script that goes onto a shopping website that auto carts and checkouts an Item for you It has a captcha In it during the end and almost never pops up if you are logged into a google account.

My program always opens up in a new chrome page and I always get the captcha. I just want to know if there is a way make the script open In a new tab on my pre-existing page (where I am signed into my google account)
(also if anyone knows how to make a captcha harvester/bypass I would appreciate on how to fit it into my script).

URL = https://etc..

here is some part of my scipt:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/(username)/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver.get(URL)
```

(also not as important I want to turn this script into a shareable application for computers where I can turn my `"raw_input"` into text boxes where people can simply type in the stuff and it would save and run the program.) ( I use stuff like `driver.find_element_by(blah).click` and `.send_keys`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37088717/9388050

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reconnect to the browser opened by webdriver with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861813/how-can-i-reconnect-to-the-browser-opened-by-webdriver-with-selenium)

Comment: None of these forums have Solutions that have helped me or that work

Comment: If you want to start your driver with your **default** profile path, instead of a new profile, then read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062789/how-to-load-default-profile-in-chrome-using-python-selenium-webdriver. This way selenium will start with your regular chrome profile.

Comment: None of these have worked for me

Comment: I want the program to start in a new tab on my pre esisting window or just for the program to run while being signed into a google account